# Showing a function is differentiable at the origin

Tags: calculus

Let $f: R^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}, & \text{if }\text{ $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{ }\text{ $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}
$$

I claim $f$ is differentiable at the origin: My attempt:

Notice

$$ 0 \leq \left| e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}} \right| < x^2 + y^2 \to 0 $$

since $e^{x} \geq x+1 > x \iff e^{-x} < \frac{1}{x} \iff e^{-\frac{1}{x}} < x$

Is this enough? or do I need to show more work? thanks